# How to find object value in array with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

How can I search in an array to see if the value exists?

```
var fruitVarietyChecked = $('input[name=fruitVariety]:checked').val();

$.getJSON('getdata.php', {fruitVariety: fruitVarietyChecked}, function(fruittype) {

            var html = '';
            $.each(fruittype, function(index, array) {

                alert( "Key: " + index + ", Value: " + array['fruittype'] );
                //shows array - Key: 0 , Value: special item

                //this is where the problem is
                if ($(array.has("special item"))){

                    $("p").text("special item" + " found at " + index);
                    return false;
                    }

                html = html + '<label><input type="radio" name="fruitType" value="' + array['fruittype'] + '" />' + array['fruittype'] + '</label> ';
            });
            $('#fruittype').html(html);
            });
}
```

So far I tried `.is` , `.has` , `.getdata` and `.inarray`, but it's getting me nowhere.

The JSON call returns: `[{"fruittype":"special item"},{"fruittype":"blue"},{"fruittype":"red"}]`

Comment: What does your array look like ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think its a syntax error:
Change `if ($(array.has("special item"))){`
to

```
if ($.inArray("special item", array) > -1){
```

**EDIT:**

If the array has complex objects then you cannot use inArray, instead you can use the jQuery filter to achieve the same, e.g:

```
    var filtered = $(array).filter(function(){
        return this.fruittype == "special item";
    });
    if(filtered.length > 0){
```

Comment: Although the answer is shown twice here, this does not seem to be working.

Comment: Can you post the array that is being returned by the JSON call?

Comment: The JSON call returns: `[{"fruittype":"special item"},{"fruittype":"blue"},{"fruittype":"red"}]`

Comment: @Jroen: Updated the post please check.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $.inArray(valueToMatch, theArray) > -1 )
```